# Sending arrays with SOAP using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

Hopefully anybody can help me with PHP to successfully parse the XML?  That’s my problem.  I get back XML on the wire, but PHP doesn’t parse it.

Neither PHP-SOAP/5.2.17 nor PHP-SOAP/5.1.6, haven’t tried yet on PHP 5.3.

```
<?PHP
echo "<html><body>\n";
echo "starting<br>\n";
echo "<pre>\n";

$wsdl = "http://192.168.16.7/api/soap/softswitch.wsdl";
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disable WSDL cache
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>true));

try {
$response = $client->get_queue_destinations($_REQUEST['username'],
$_REQUEST['password'], $_REQUEST['queue']);

# echo "$response";

print_r($response);
# var_dump($response);

$x = serialize($client->__getLastResponse());
print_r($x);

#$xml = simplexml_load_string($client->__getLastResponse());
#print_r($xml);

# print "Request: \n".htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
# print "Response: \n".htmlentities($client->__getLastResponse())."\n";
# echo "</pre>\n";

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "<pre>\n";
echo "Caught Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
// Show the actual XML sent and received
print "Request: \n".$client->__getLastRequest() ."\n";
print "Response: \n".$client->__getLastResponse()."\n";
echo "</pre>\n";
}

echo "</pre>\n";
echo "finished\n";
echo "</body><html>\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. visit https://www.php.net/serialize

"serialize function cannot be used for xml parsing"

```
#$xml = simplexml_load_string($client->__getLastResponse());
#print_r($xml);
```

Simple XML is an object and it cannot be print_r in that way.